# How many bullets can Deadpool's guns carry?

Tags: realism, x-men-cinematic-universe, deadpool

In the movie Deadpool, on the bridge fight scene, Deadpool says he only has 12 bullets. But those weapons looks like Desert Eagles, and he has two. So that means they only have six round capacity?

[image]

Comment: The weapons pictured here are Desert Eagle, but I don't know why caliber it is. The .50 has a 7 round capacity and the .44 has an 8 round capacity. Why he only has 12? Maybe he shot a few previously. Maybe he only loaded 12?

Comment: @DustinDavis He just came from a cab ride just to wait for the bad guy. I dont think he shoot any round before that, but that is one possibility. Btw if you dont watch the movie highly recommend, just saw it yesterday.

Comment: @DustinDavis But thanks for confirm is a Desert Eagle, my only experience with weapons is from *Call of Dutty* ;)

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza is that Indian version of COD? I see many people named dutta/dutty in India ;)

Comment: @Vishwa Nope just a typo. And english isnt my first lenguage

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Just kidding. Thanks for the your inputs :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From my research for the [Can a single bullet from a handgun kill three people in the way Deadpool did?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/55640/can-a-single-bullet-from-a-handgun-kill-three-people-in-the-way-deadpool-did/55677#55677) question, he seems to have not fully loaded his weapon.

From [IMFDB](http://www.imfdb.org/wiki/Deadpool_(2016)#IWI_Desert_Eagle_Mark_XIX):

> Deadpool (Ryan Reynolds) can be seen **dual-wielding IWI Desert Eagle Mark XIX pistols** as his primary firearms, using them to great effect. His Desert Eagles are current-production Mark XIX models with over-barrel Picatinny-style rails made by IWI in Israel. They are recognizable by their safeties, which are retained from the original production Mark XIX; the U.S.-made Magnum Research version, in contrast, now has the "teardrop"-style safety found on the original Mark I.
>
> **The Desert Eagles used in the films are chambered in .50 AE, based on shots of the shell casings (with .50 AE clearly visible) and the lack of fluting on the barrels.** Strangely, they are apparently not fully loaded, as he states he has "12 bullets" in the highway fight. He shoots 7 rounds from the gun in his left hand and 5 from the one in his right hand, meaning one gun was fully loaded and the other wasn't. **Desert Eagle handguns in .50 AE hold 7+1 rounds**. Also, at another noteworthy point, every primer of the spent casings are marked with the number of the round spent (from 12 to 1).

The +1 being a round in the chamber. A 7 round clip is the standard package for this gun, and Deadpool was not using an extended clip. The standard clip even has the rounds numbered on the clip (4, 5, 6, 7).

[image]

The extended clips stick out from the bottom of the gun.

[image]

**As we see multiple times, for budget reasons, I mean Wade have ADD, he often forgets his weapons, so he likely forgot to load the gun up all the way.**

That, or as mentioned in the comments, he shot some off before the cab ride.

### Update:

You can clearly see a real clip used in the movie. It has the 4, 5, 6, 7 holes. Deadpool just underloaded the weapon.

[image]

Comment: the more you live the more you learn, I knew IMDB, didnt know they need IMFDB

Comment: wow, did you watch the movie again to get that picture with the underloaded clip?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza ha no, I was googling for a good picture of the clip and found it. And its on IMFDB too. I never scrolled down all the way.